# Python function calling

Tags: python, class, pyqt

I have the following class

```
class GUI( QtGui.QMainWindow ):
    '''
    classdocs
    '''
    """**********************************************************************"""
    """              Constructor                                             """
    """**********************************************************************"""
    def __init__( self, parent = None ):
          self.udpClass = MCUDP.MCUDP()

    def insertText( self, string ):
          string = time.ctime() + ': ' + string + '\n'
          self.messageField.insertPlainText( string )
```

And I also have MCUDP class created in the GUI class. My question is how can I reach the GUI class insertText function in MCUDP

UPDATED

this is the MCUDP

```
'''
Created on 09.06.2011

@author: robu
'''
import socket
import time
import MCGui;

class MCUDP( object ):
    '''
    classdocs
    '''
    """**********************************************************************"""
    """              UDP: Broadcasting                                       """
    """**********************************************************************"""
    def UDPBroadcast( self, ip = "255.255.255.255", UDPport = 15000, message = 'whoisthere', timeout = 10, TCPport = 30000 ):
        # ip="255.255.255.255" stands for a broadcast        
        ip = str( ip )
        s = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP )
        s.setsockopt( socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, True )
        s.settimeout( timeout )
        ownIP = socket.gethostbyname( socket.gethostname() )
        if message.upper() == 'WHOISTHERE':
            message = message + ';' + ownIP + ':' + str( TCPport )
        #print "Trying to send '%s' to IP %s, Port %s!" %(message, ip, port)
        #self.Eingang.put("Trying to send '%s' to IP %s, Port %s!" %(message, ip, UDPport))
        s.sendto( message, ( ip, UDPport ) )
        answer = "%s: '%s' broadcasted to %s!" % ( time.asctime(), message, ip )
        GUI.insertText( 'test' );
        #print answer
        s.close()
        return answer
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two objects that need to communicate with each other, which is a fairly standard communication problem.  There's a number of ways that this problem can be solved:

**(1) Dependency Injection** - Make your MCUDP() class require the MCGUI class at construction time.
You'll then have it available whenever you need:

```
class MCUDP(object):
    def __init__(self, gui): self.gui = gui
    def UDPBroadcast(...):
        # ... as necessary ...
        self.gui.insertText("YourText")

class MCGUI(...)
    def __init__( self, parent = None ):
        self.udpClass = MCUDP.MCUDP(self)
```

If you do this your MCUDP class becomes dependent on an object that implements all the methods of `self.gui` that MCUDP uses. In other words, MCUDP is now coupled directly to the MCGUI class. Of course, the MCGUI class is already dependent on MCUDP to some extent.

**(2) Message passing** - In Qt, Signals and slots. The idiomatic Qt route uses messages instead of function calls:

```
class MCGUI(...)
    def __init__( self, parent = None ):
        self.udpClass = MCUDP.MCUDP()
        self.connect(self.udpClass, PYSIGNAL("textUpdated"), self.insertText);
```

And then you just need to make your MCUDP class a QObject so that it can emit events:

```
class MCUDP(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QObject.__init__(self, parent)
    def UDPBroadcast(...):
        # ... as necessary ...
        self.emit(PYSIGNAL("textUpdated"), ("yourText",))
```

The benefit of this is now MCUDP doesn't need to know anything about the MCGUI class which will make both testing and future changes easier.

Answer (score 1):

It is available as `insertText` during declaration and as `GUI.insertText` or `GUI().insertText` during execution. If you are not sure where you are, try both :).
I would say which one you need if you posted the actual full code.

**[update]**
Your MCDUP class is not 'created in the GUI class'. You just create a an instance of MCDUP and hold a reference to it inside GUI. The reference is one-way, so if you need to access parent GUI instance, you need a back-reference, something like:

```
class GUI(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
          self.udp = MCUDP.MCUDP(gui=self)
```

And then in MCDUP:

```
class MCUDP(object):
    def __init__(self, gui):
        self.gui = gui
    def udp_broadcast(self, ...):
        ...
        self.gui.insertText('test')
        ...
```

I also made the code a little more [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)-friedly.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the second option suggested by Kaleb Pederson is the way to go.
Nevertheless if you want a reference to the MainWindow you can save it 
as a property of your QApplication's instance.
When you start your application:

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
...
mainwindow = GUI()
app.setProperty("mainwindow", QVariant(mainwindow))
```

Then when you want to use the reference:

```
...
mainwindow = qApp.property('mainwindow').toPyObject()
...
```